# how to get parameters from switch or file

Tags: powershell, parameters

I've seen in the past before I started scripting that a powershell script that requires a hostname parameter. it could either by typed in like `Script.PS1 "hostname"`
but you could also run the script in the following method:

```
gc hostnames.txt | script.ps1
```

and in this way you could list a number of hostnames in your text file.

how is this achieved.
my parameters looks as follows

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [ValidateSet("C","K")]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [String]$Action,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [String]$Computers

    )
```

Comment: The question asked is not about getting parameters from the `pipeline` although the `syntax submitted` implies that.  The suggested duplicate doesn't address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked you could use syntax something like

```
gc hostnames.txt | % {  .\script.ps1 -Action A -Computers $_ }
```

and it would call `script.ps1` once for each line in `hostnames.txt`.

The `$_` is a placeholder for the current value of the array being iterated by the `... | % ...` syntax.

Comment: Correct answer. I'd like to add that I personally prefer to make scripts readable by not using 'gc' but Get-Content and not using '%' but ForEach-Object or ForEach. This makes it a lot easier to understand and especially for the ones without a lot of experience.

Comment: Old habits die hard for lazy hackers